# Взять два цвета у объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Если у объекта есть два цвета (красный и синий), первым идет красный, к нему я получаю доступ PlayerCube.GetComponent().material.color, вопрос, как получить доступ к второму цвету?

P.S. Нужно прозрачность обоих поменять

Comment: приложите код к вопросу, пока не ясно, что вы хотите получить и откуда

Comment: В каком это смысле не ясно? Взять цвет объекта, не важно какого, важно что второй цвет, если что я об unity

Comment: покажите код объекта, потому что в объекте он может иметь обозначение и `color2` и `Startcolor`и множество других, однако для воспроизведения ответа на ваш вопрос, нужно понимать в какой части кода и что искать, пока ясно что существует объект из которого можно взять  PlayerCube.GetComponent().material.color, который вроде как цвет, но что такое цвет 2 не понятно вообще.

Comment: @Monomax, http://uploads.ru/Y4Til.png

Comment: у меня фаервол, так что ваше изображение мне не видно(((

Comment: @Monomax, грубо говорю, я повесил на объект два цвета, в инспекторе видны "Материал" и "Материал1" которые созданы в папке проекта, т.е.  наложены на куб два цвета, и мне нужно обратиться к двум, как это можно сделать?

Comment: так же "грубо" отвечаю `PlayerCube.GetComponent().material2.color`

Comment: @Monomax, спасибо, работает

Comment: Материал и цвет - разные вещи, не путайте.

Answer (score -3):

GameObject.GetComponent().materials[#].color; // где # номер индекса цвета

Comment: можно было дать и ответить

Comment: что сразу помешало это сделать?